# Handling signals in erl_child_setup

Tags: heroku, erlang, signals

I have a problem with deploying Elixir/Phoenix application on Heroku.
When Heroku restarts or stops the dyno, it sends `SIGTERM` to all user processes.
Erlang starts 3 processes on application startup:

- `erl_child_setup`
- Erlang Port Mapper Deamon
- Actual application

Sending `SIGTERM` to `erl_child_setup` results in crashing the VM and generating `erl_crash.dump`.

Sending `SIGTERM` to all processes is used quite often to ensure a graceful shutdown.
While researching the crash cause I saw that people had similar issues with stopping docker containers running Erlang.

My question is:
Is there a way to gracefully shutdown the VM when `erl_child_setup` gets `SIGTERM` or is there a way to instruct Heroku not to send `SIGTERM` to `erl_child_setup`?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue with a elixir/Phoenix app, did you manage to find a solution?

Comment: I’ve submitted the issue to Erlang VM maintainers, and it was classified as a bug. The PR with the fix is already merged, so I hope the problem will go away with next Erlang release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed in `OTP-23.1.4`, according to the reported [bug](https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-576), and [this PR](https://github.com/erlang/otp/pull/1730).